# How can I easily implement service monitoring using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring

I am wondering if there is a way to implement a simple monitoring like checking if a SSH port is open, or a SFTP service is responding on a machine using only AWS.

Is it possible and if so, how?

For the purpose of this question simple TCP port checks with or without TLS should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well best would be to use AWS Lambda and setup a bunch of Scheduled events ( Cron Job Like ) that will send calls to certain ports in certain protocols. And even push out a notification to SNS if something fails.

```
Lambda Function -> Notify to SNS -> Broad Cast to Subscribers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/login) for monitoring any HTTP links,Port or Ping website url.